# Send TCP packet to the same source

Tags: linux-kernel, router, tcp, netfilter

I want to design a system which reduces travel time of packet what is happening, in reality, am I send an SYN bit from the client side, this bit travel through the router then to server and server reply SYN+ACK which also travel through the router to the client.

So I just want something else like what if the client sends SYN to router, router then send this to server and copy this packet modify SYN to SYN+ACK and send back to client before server can send after server send this SYN+ACK to router, router just accept it(see it as the reply is coming) and discard it.

To achieve above goal, I design a setup in which I have one laptop which sends and receive packet from two ethernet interface and other one is desktop which acts as router(packets are coming and it only forward it to its destination) I set up the routing table from both side and enable the IP forwarding on desktop(which act as router).

All are working fine, on a laptop I have server and client program which send the packet and receive it but the problem is that I want to send the packets to from where it was coming (to source itself) so I modify the packet on routing side using Netfilter module, copy the entire skb(using skb_copy) and interchange its ip source and destination(I did this on NF_INET_PREROUTING) and also interchange the port number but the packet always goes to destination.

What other modification do I need to be done to send the packet to its source itself?

Answer (score 0):

Before all, you have to deal here with some details.

First, on SYN-ACK packet, the server sends its sequence. So if in the router you modify the packet and send back to client, what will be your sequence? It's should be the same like the server will send and the server did not send anything yet.

Second, in the handshake there are several agreements like MSS, SACK enabled etc. So you can't to it on behalf of server.

About the question itself, you should do it in PRE_ROUTING, change the IP addresses and ports, and fix the checksum of both IP and TCP.